SOLVED - DB Error: insufficient permissions when separating log tables from main civiCRM DB
I have a site running civiCRM 5.72.1 on Joomla 3.10.12.
My civicrm_log tables are huge, so I planned to separate them from the Joomla database where they have been 5+ years.
To do this I:

Created a new mysql DB and user with full permissions (https://app.screencast.com/W4b3XM38FE3Qh)
Set Logging to No in civiAdmin
Updated civicrm.settings.php in both administrator/components/civicrm and /components/civicrm to have CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN point to the new mysql DB
Exported the log tables from the CMS DB
Imported them into the new DB.
Returned to civiAdmin and set Logging to Yes

When I save the changes in civiCRM, I see the error [DB Error: insufficient permissions]
Is there something I'm missing? Why would I get this error (only happens if I try to enable Logging)?

You probably need to delete & rebuild the triggers in your CMS DB so they point to your new separate LOG DB.
References:
https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#trigger-rebuild
Are there 'cv' commands for these operations?

Thanks for the pointer. I dropped all the existing triggers in the the CMS DB where civiCRM data exists, and then called:
https://mydomain.com/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1
But no triggers were created in the CMS DB.
The civicrm.settings.php file has CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN set to point to the new logging database.
Any thoughts as to why the triggers wouldn't be recreated?

Is your logging set to "yes" in Civi Admin?

Excellent question! And I tried to enable it, but the setting won't save (which is odd since any other changes that I make do save without error). See https://1drv.ms/v/s!ApZ2h3V5HB1io_47h89O4h8X4maF2Q?e=fHElmQ

Sounds like the old triggers are still in place. I faced something similar when I split off the civi logs to a separate db. In my case, the old triggers in the cms db were still there and I couldn't save the logging setting like you. You're likely getting that "insufficient privileges" error in the Civi UI when trying to save the logging value because the old civicrm_setting_after_update trigger on the civicrm_setting table is still in place. I'd suggest going into PhpMyAdmin, open your cms db, drop all the triggers (at least all the Civicrm triggers)...

... then you can go back into the Civi UI and turn ON logging again. Once you have logging turned on, then you can rebuild your triggers using the URL command above.

It's very odd. I've deleted all the triggers in the CMS database, and I've dropped all the log_civicrm_* tables. I've updated the civicrm.settings.php file to set the DSN for logging to point to the new DB. In civiCRM status page I can rebuild the triggers, but still I get the [DB Error: insufficient permissions] when I try to set Logging to Yes. If I set Logging to Yes, and change another option on the page Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, etc.) the other option will save, but not the Yes for logging. So mysterious!

... The logging DB has a different username and password, but that shouldn't matter, since it is correctly specified in the setttings.php file.

I think you need to use the same MySQL username and password for both databases (Civicrm and Civicrm Log). The triggers run entirely within the MySQL layer. The DSN settings in civicrm.settings.php don't affect the running of the triggers. That's for reading/writing from the PHP app layer. If you take a look at one of your triggers (on your cms db), you'll see it's trying to do a SQL INSERT on the corresponding log table in your civicrm log db. I would try using the same user/pw on both dbs.

Oh awesome, that is the solution! Thank you so much for the back and forth to sort this out. Hopefully others will find this information helpful!

Awesome! Happy to hear it worked for you.
